# WPF Tookit - IntegerUpDown

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpftoolkit

How do I get the value from the IntergerUpDown control?
I'am using this : http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown
Here is the code from MainWindow.xaml

```
 <extToolkit:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=CurrentCount}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="119,111,0,148" Increment="1" Maximum="10" Minimum="1" Width="100"/>
```

Here is the code from MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public int CurrentCount { get; set; }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentCount = 10;
         int len = Talker.BlahBlahBlah(textBox1.Text, CurrentCount);
    }
```

So basically I want to pass the value chosen by the user as an int into the method BlahBlahBlah. Do I need to create a View Model and bind it to a CurrentValue property? Can you please provide me with sample code which gets the value from the UI?

So here is my Talker Class:

```
 class Talker
{
    public static int BlahBlahBlah(string thingToSay, int numberOfTimes)
    {
        string finalString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
        {
            finalString = finalString + thingToSay + "\n";
        }

        MessageBox.Show(finalString);
        return finalString.Length;
    }
}
```

This is the method inside ViewModelBase:

```
    public virtual int CurrentCount
    {
        get { return _CurrentCount; }
        set
        {
            _CurrentCount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentCount");
        }
    }
```

Question is how do I link it together??

Peace

Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper, MVVM-correct way of doing this is to bind the Value to a property on your ViewModel.

```
public int CurrentCount
{
    get { return _CurrentCount; }
    set
    {
        _CurrentCount = value;

    }
}
```

I recommend [Josh Smith's excellent article on MVVM.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

One thing you might want to do later is update the `CurrentCount` from code and have it reflect correctly in the IntegerUpDown control. To do this, you'll have to inherit from the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You can use his `ViewModelBase` class which does just that. Then, your `ViewModel` inherits from `ViewModelBase` and can call `OnPropertyChanged` to send property changed notifications:

```
public int CurrentCount
{
    get { return _CurrentCount; }
    set
    {
        _CurrentCount = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentCount");            
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Aphex, 
Cool, thanks for the answer. I'll try it out when I get home, I wanted to do it correctly which will be beneficial for my learning.

Comment: I'd a read thru the article.. and still a bit confused. When you have a spare moment could you help me out?

Comment: Sure, what problem are you running into? You can update your original post or just create a new question and link it here, and I'll take a look (and I'm sure other MVVM nerds on here would be glad to help too.)

Comment: Hey - I've already edited the original post. My question, is once I've added the CurrentCount..how do I get the value from it when I click the button? Do I need to add the command class as per Josh Smith?

Comment: If it's bound to `CurrentCount`, then all you have to do is look at `CurrentCount`... I think you understand this, though, so let me ask a different question: what are you trying to make the button do?

Comment: Sorry, what I am trying to do is.. when the user clicks on the button is to grab the value from the NumericUpOrdown and pass that value to my Talker class.

Comment: You already do this, according to your post above. Simply pass `CurrentCount` to the `BlahBlahBlah` function. Since `CurrentCount` is the source property for the Binding to your IntegerUpDown control, it will always reflect the current `Value` of the control.

Comment: Sweet - I'll check it out when I head home. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to name the `IntegerUpDown` control

```
<extToolkit:IntegerUpDown 
    x:Name="CurrentCountUpDown" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="119,111,0,148" 
    Increment="1" 
    Maximum="10" 
    Minimum="1" 
    Width="100"/>
```

And then just refer to that control by name in your event handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int len = Talker.BlahBlahBlah(textBox1.Text, CurrentCountUpDown.Value);
}
```

Comment: Hi RQDQ,

Great answer.. what is the proper way to do it? Create another class called ModelViewModel and do it that way?